# match with different types of words -regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I have to have a regular expression that matches the following lines:

```
ESR/EXR
ESR [1]
(ESR) [1]
(ESR) [1] 
RARB [1]
 ESR [1] # Space before word
```

But not match:

```
ESR
(ESR)
```

I have tried `(\w+)[?\s\/]\[\w+\]?\s` and `^?\((\w+)?\)[?\s\/]\[\w+\]?\s`, but I can't figure out a way to match all the case with one regexp.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `/(.*)/`?

Comment: Without telling us what you **don't** want to match, it's impossible to help you!

Comment: yes but still the first one couldn't be matched.

Comment: Maybe you could add a few (different) examples of lines that you **don't** want your reggae to match. Otherwise, we can only assume that you simply wan't to match everything!

Comment: I don't want to match the last two. Is that helpful?!

Comment: How about `Foo [99]` ?

Comment: @user1958532 The `[?\s\/]` part looks a bit suspicious as there are no question marks in any of the examples. What is it meant to achieve?

Comment: isn't ? is to match 0 or 1 time? So I used to match a white space if there is one.

Comment: there wouldn't be a case with multiple digits within the square brackets.

Comment: @user1958532 Not when it's in a character class. `[?\s\/]` means a question mark, a whitespace character or a slash. May I suggest you start with a regex tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I've really understood your needs, but how about:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my $re = qr~\(?\w+\)?(?:[ /].+)~;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say /$re/ ? "OK : $_" : "KO : $_";
}

__DATA__
ESR/EXR
ESR [1]
(ESR) [1]
(ESR) [1] 
RARB [1]
ESR
(ESR)
```

**Output:**

```
OK : ESR/EXR
OK : ESR [1]
OK : (ESR) [1]
OK : (ESR) [1] 
OK : RARB [1]
KO : ESR
KO : (ESR)
```